# ДепреСняк или депреССняк — как правильно?

Tags: орфография, жаргон

*Однажды приходит октябрь, а за ним — дожди,

И вместе с дождями — тоска, [**депрессняк**](https://art-hogus.livejournal.com/13160.html#/13160.html), хандра...*

*— У нее [**депресняк**](http://knijky.ru/books/zov-kukushki?page=111) был. Ага, на лекарствах сидела. Как и я. Такая, бывает, тоска накатит, сил нет. Это ж болезнь, а не что.*

[**Словарь синонимов ASIS. В.Н. Тришин. 2013**](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/328079/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BA): **депреСняк**.
[**Викисловарь**](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BA): **депреССняк**.

А как правильно-то? Подскажите, пожалуйста, — я не смогла определить.

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос № 216204

> Как правильно: "депресняк" или "депрессняк"? Спасибо.

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> В словарях жаргона зафиксированы оба варианта написания